# mysql equivalent of oracle utl_file

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, text-files, flat-file

I'm starting on stored procedures with mySQL and need to convert some procedures created for Oracle Database 11gR2 using UTL_FILE package to generate execution logs.

Can anyone help me, telling me if there is any similar form in mySQL?

Grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after long hours of searching I conclude that there are internal constraints in mySQL for direct writing text files.

The contour that occurs to me is to write the log messages and debugging on a table in the database, and then save the relevant records in a text file.

Similarly, grateful to all who may have tried to help.